git-filter-repo changes only apply to some but not all commits that edited during rewrite
I'm working on migrating my team repo from Bitbucket Server to GitHub but encountered problems with faulty commit data like the list below (result from running git fsck --full)
PS D:\Test\jee6.git> git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error in commit 19ca73d4eaf7b40bd3b6f06c8bf9b90f40227dcf: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 636767ba507ca6853cdb78df9d3af29b9221e414: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 8abc8a46fc1745db92b99ce8fae8bad949b03e9e: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit f6491d6fdd257ba5c7173a8b2d28cde405f1761f: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit edd93b99ef6d11e655f56777674b371fd8b145cf: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 8a069292c930d8637d3cc5e0775efdc5acd23545: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 8cc718a390ccf3180172e46c8d543d640be2e4b7: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 5cde0f624fb47a0f32016eaf70ea42af2a0ec0c8: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 07b8e4e6d64603e70115bfc2912420929c687b54: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 7719abfafc27f4e303b20eb694a6caef15fb2a0c: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit c836419cbf8303232dce09497d5eb211a96b5648: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 5c6efdde0712f4bc801dfdfe285b40aca96ce6a2: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 9d8b5204c68dff3fd258d570fe9971a18da1e127: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 44e5d46bb8d8dda8bc80636e6ad5bddcbe654407: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit af59c8f25d60c7a55a0933d93991a02d391f2ec3: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 0c953871db294d3431265aa9d92b738b4aca77d9: missingSpaceBeforeDate: invalid author/committer line - missing space before date
Checking objects: 100% (912825/912825), done.
Checking connectivity: 912826, done.

So I tried to use git-filter-repo to rewrite the history of these commits using both --email-callback and --commit-callback like below
git-filter-repo --email-callback "
    if email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.comFix'):
        print('1 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    elif email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.c '):
        print('2 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    elif email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.intAdd'):
        print('3 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    elif email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.com \\<'):
        print('4 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    elif email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.co '):
        print('5 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    elif email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.com '):
        print('6 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    elif email.startswith(b'Test.user@example.com>modified'):
        print('7 \\n')
        return b'Test.user@example.com'
    return email
" --commit-callback "
    if commit.original_id == b'0c953871db294d3431265aa9d92b738b4aca77d9':
        print('Edited commit message')
        commit.committer_date = b' 1444191970 +1100'
    return commit
"

or another approach is by using only --commit-callback
git-filter-repo --commit-callback "
    from pprint import pprint
    if commit.original_id == b'19ca73d4eaf7b40bd3b6f06c8bf9b90f40227dcf':
        print('Edited commit message - 19ca73d4eaf7b40bd3b6f06c8bf9b90f40227dcf')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'636767ba507ca6853cdb78df9d3af29b9221e414':
        print('Edited commit message - 636767ba507ca6853cdb78df9d3af29b9221e414')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'8abc8a46fc1745db92b99ce8fae8bad949b03e9e':
        print('Edited commit message - 8abc8a46fc1745db92b99ce8fae8bad949b03e9e')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'f6491d6fdd257ba5c7173a8b2d28cde405f1761f':
        print('Edited commit message - f6491d6fdd257ba5c7173a8b2d28cde405f1761f')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'edd93b99ef6d11e655f56777674b371fd8b145cf':
        print('Edited commit message - edd93b99ef6d11e655f56777674b371fd8b145cf')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'8a069292c930d8637d3cc5e0775efdc5acd23545':
        print('Edited commit message - 8a069292c930d8637d3cc5e0775efdc5acd23545')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.author_date = b'1403503689 +1200'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_date = b'1403503689 +1200'
    elif commit.original_id == b'8cc718a390ccf3180172e46c8d543d640be2e4b7':
        print('Edited commit message - 8cc718a390ccf3180172e46c8d543d640be2e4b7')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.author_date = b'1403056506 +1200'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_date = b'1403056506 +1200'
    elif commit.original_id == b'5cde0f624fb47a0f32016eaf70ea42af2a0ec0c8':
        print('Edited commit message - 5cde0f624fb47a0f32016eaf70ea42af2a0ec0c8')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.author_date = b'1402957143 +1200'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_date = b'1402957143 +1200'
    elif commit.original_id == b'07b8e4e6d64603e70115bfc2912420929c687b54':
        print('Edited commit message - 07b8e4e6d64603e70115bfc2912420929c687b54')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'7719abfafc27f4e303b20eb694a6caef15fb2a0c':
        print('Edited commit message - 7719abfafc27f4e303b20eb694a6caef15fb2a0c')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'c836419cbf8303232dce09497d5eb211a96b5648':
        print('Edited commit message - c836419cbf8303232dce09497d5eb211a96b5648')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.author_date = b'1402640540 +1200'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_date = b'1402640540 +1200'
    elif commit.original_id == b'5c6efdde0712f4bc801dfdfe285b40aca96ce6a2':
        print('Edited commit message - 5c6efdde0712f4bc801dfdfe285b40aca96ce6a2')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.author_date = b'1402639764 +1200'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_date = b'1402639764 +1200'
    elif commit.original_id == b'9d8b5204c68dff3fd258d570fe9971a18da1e127':
        print('Edited commit message - 9d8b5204c68dff3fd258d570fe9971a18da1e127')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'44e5d46bb8d8dda8bc80636e6ad5bddcbe654407':
        print('Edited commit message - 44e5d46bb8d8dda8bc80636e6ad5bddcbe654407')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'af59c8f25d60c7a55a0933d93991a02d391f2ec3':
        print('Edited commit message - af59c8f25d60c7a55a0933d93991a02d391f2ec3')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
    elif commit.original_id == b'0c953871db294d3431265aa9d92b738b4aca77d9':
        print('Edited commit message - 0c953871db294d3431265aa9d92b738b4aca77d9')
        pprint(commit.__dict__)
        commit.author_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.author_date = b' 1444191970 +1100'
        commit.committer_email = b'Test.User@example.com'
        commit.committer_date = b' 1444191970 +1100'
"

After it finished running, the result came back by running git fsck --full still show errors for some commits in the list (6 out of 16).
λ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error in commit 0c953871db294d3431265aa9d92b738b4aca77d9: missingSpaceBeforeDate: invalid author/committer line - missing space before date
error in commit 8a069292c930d8637d3cc5e0775efdc5acd23545: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 8cc718a390ccf3180172e46c8d543d640be2e4b7: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 5cde0f624fb47a0f32016eaf70ea42af2a0ec0c8: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit c836419cbf8303232dce09497d5eb211a96b5648: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
error in commit 5c6efdde0712f4bc801dfdfe285b40aca96ce6a2: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
Checking objects: 100% (99211/99211), done.

Since the history was re-written, I'm not sure how git fsck --full still see problems from old hash ID.
Checking the commit using git cat-file -p <hash ID> and I can see the data is updated (no longer in invalid format).
I wonder if I miss any steps to make sure the changes are applied and how can git fsck --full can still see the problems.

Are you sure that you don't have refs or reflogs lingering around that still reference the old history? Clone the repo and fsck there again.

I force push to remote repo & try to clone the repo again but the check still comes back the same.
If I run git-filter-repo looking for that hash id, it is no longer available.

Don't push and clone: you might receive unwanted old history from the remote repository. Just clone to a different directory: git clone file://$PWD ../foo; cd ../foo; git fsck.

I just gave this a try by running git-filter-repo on a fresh bare clone of the repo and then clone to a different directory and running git fsck, the problem still persists for these 6 commits.
I previously did a find in files and saw that the hash id is being referred in packed-ref as ref/replace/<hash ID>
